# Why doesn't my multipart/form-data file upload work on a new server?

Tags: php, apache

I have a multipart form I've just moved to a new server which uploads an image. It works perfectly on one, but not on the other. Regular form data works, but my php script to process the upload doesn't acknowledge that there are any files.

ie:

```
if($_FILES['product_image'][name] != '') {

    // store the image

}
```

It basically ignores this `$_FILES` variable as though it doesn't exist.

I vaguely recall this issue happening in the past but I can't remember what it was that solved it. Is there some configuration for apache setup, or something I am missing?

Here is a `var_dump($_FILES)` from the upload:

> array(2) { ["product_image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(11)
>   "TEST.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14)
>   "/tmp/phpYP9AKA" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(38652) }

Comment: `var_dump($_FILES)` to see what's in it? Also, please quote your array keys `$_FILES['product_image']['name']`, it will work without, but relies on PHP assuming you meant to use strings instead of constants.

Comment: what is the file size limit in php on your new server? what is the temp directory? are there proper permissions in the new server / php to write a file to temp at all?

Comment: file size limit is 30M, script upload time is 300 seconds, the file i'm uploading is 30k. i'm checking the temp directory now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the critical part:

```
["error"]=> int(4)
```

The upload failed with [error code 4](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php) - "No file was uploaded".

Without seeing your form, there's no way to diagnos this.

Comment: I can see in the chrome status bar that the file is being transferred, so the form is fine. And looking in the var_dump the filename is there. So the problem must be in the actual storing of the file into the tmp directory - do you think that is true?

Comment: Please note the var_dump was showing there was another image, which was for another form element which I was not uploading an image for - i've removed it since it is irrelevant and updated the original post. As you can see, it says ['error']=>int(0).